# Characteristic curves of the advection equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to understand Pg. 2 of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.3809).
Why do the characteristics of the equation
$$
\partial_tu + (1-\rho)^2\partial_\rho u = 0
$$
satisfy the differential equation
$$
\dfrac{d\rho}{dt} = -(1-\rho(t))^2
$$
rather than $d\rho/dt = (1-\rho(t))^2$? Why is there a negative sign? I was under the impression that in general, the characteristics of an equation $a\partial_xu+b\partial_yu = 0$ satisfy $dy/dx = b/a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that it is a typo. Please see Figure 1 of that paper (attached below).

As time $t$ increases, $\rho$ increases, so its derivative must be positive.

[image: Figure 1].

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$$\partial_tu + (1-\rho)^2\partial_\rho u = 0 $$
The characteristic system of ODEs (Charpit-Lagrange) is :
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{d\rho}{(1-\rho)^2}=\frac{du}{0}$$
A first characteristic equation, coming from $du=0$, is :
$$u=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation, coming from $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{d\rho}{(1-\rho)^2}$ , is :
$$t+\frac{1}{\rho-1}=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE on the form of implicit equation $c_1=F(c_2)$ is :
$$\boxed{u=F\left(t+\frac{1}{\rho-1}\right)}$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function, to be determined according to some boundary conditions.

So, you are right to point out that  $\frac{d\rho}{dt} = (1-\rho(t))^2$ on the characteristic curves.